# Jolt Numeric Constant

Tags: jolt

In Jolt it is possible to assign a constant value to a field by prefixing the constant value with `#` as below.

```
{ "#2": "myField"}
```

But this constant is always added as a string value. How can I add it as a numeric value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "default" or the newer "modify-default-beta".

```
[
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "myField": 2
    }
  }
]
```